# Инициализация свойств в C#

Tags: c#, ооп

Нашёл следующий пример в интернете, но не до конца понимаю как он работает:

```
class Credit
{
    public virtual decimal Sum { get; set; }
}
class LongCredit : Credit
{
    private decimal sum;
    public override decimal Sum
    {
        get
        {
            return sum;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 1000)
            {
                sum = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LongCredit credit = new LongCredit { Sum = 6000 };
        credit.Sum = 490;
        Console.WriteLine(credit.Sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Почему здесь используются фигурные скобки {} при создании экземпляра класса LongCredit? Насколько я понял, фигурные скобки используются при работе с методами, но здесь мы задаём значение поля Sum. Можно ли задать значение поля через обыкновенные скобки? `new LongCredit(Sum = 6000);`

Вопрос возник по отношению к этой строке:

```
 LongCredit credit = new LongCredit { Sum = 6000 };
```

Comment: Связано ли это с тем, что не указан конструктор для класса LongCredit, и фигурные скобки "заменяют" конструктор?

Comment: Прочитайте кто-нибудь уже спецификацию языка. [Вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) ссылка!

Answer (score 5):

Это [инициализатор объекта](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#object-initializers):

> An object initializer specifies values for zero or more fields, properties or indexed elements of an object.
> antlr:
>
> > ```
> > object_initializer
> >     : '{' member_initializer_list? '}'
> >     | '{' member_initializer_list ',' '}'
> >     ;
> > ```

С помощью инициализатора при создании объекта можно сразу задать значения для полей, свойств и индексированных элементов создаваемого объекта.

Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    public int Field;
    public int Property { get; set; }
    public Test Another;

}

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Test
        {
            //поле
            Field = 1,
            //свойство
            Property = 2,
            //создание нового объекта со своим инициализатором            
            Another =  new Test{Field = 3}
        };
        var d = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            //установка элемента по индексу
            ["hello"] = "world"
        };

        Console.WriteLine($"{p.Field} {p.Property} {p.Another.Field}"); //1, 2, 3
        Console.WriteLine(d["hello"]); //world
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Если говорит проще, то запись:

```
LongCredit credit = new LongCredit { Sum = 6000 };
```

эквивалентна следующей:

```
LongCredit credit = new LongCredit();
credit.Sum = 6000;
```

Через «обыкновенные скобки» задавать произвольные поля/свойства нельзя, т.к. через них вызывается конкретный конструктор с конкретными аргументами. Для того чтобы в него что-то передать нужно создать в конструкторе соответствующий аргумент.

Comment: Вопрос про полиморфизм свойств же?

Comment: @aepot Насколько я понял, у автора проблемы в основном с непониманием «фигурных скобок». В заголовке написано про полиморфизм, но я не понял что про него можно написать.

Comment: В таком случае, теоретически можно переименовать вопрос, чтобы не конфузить тех, кто будет искать информацию про полиморфизм и натыкаться на этот вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Теоретически да, но, думаю, это лучше у автора уточнить.

Answer (score 3):

[Вот](http://plssite.ru/csharp/csharp_object_init_article.html)

Есть несколько способов инициализации объектов:

```cs
// Конструктор
var a = new Person("Иван", 26);


// Конструктор и установка ещё одного значения
// Вариант 1:
var a = new Person("Иван", 26);
a.Height = 190;

// Вариант 2:
var a = new Person("Иван", 26) { Height = 190 };


// Если нет конструктора, но нужно установить несколько значений:
// Вариант 1:
var a = new Person();
a.Name = "Иван";
a.Age = 26;
a.Height = 190;

//Вариант 2:
var a  = new Person { Name = "Иван", Age = 26, Height = 190 }
```

Это просто более удобная инициализация (с полиморфизмом никак не связана)